# Android textView layers not showing properly

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

i have an android app, that shows some fragments after swiping,

the textView in my second fragment layout is not showing properly,

i have done a visualisation of the layout in hierarchyviewer,

and see that for my second layout the frame shows to the right, how to fix this?

[image]

this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/gray_background">

    <com.egoclean.android.widget.flinger.ViewFlinger
        android:id="@+id/flinger"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="1. HOW TO PREPARE THE SKIN"
                android:textColor="#da002e" />

             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:textColor="#333333" 
                android:text="@string/taping_prepare"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

               <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:textColor="#da002e"
                    android:text="2. WHERE TO APPLY THE TAPeE" />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:textColor="#da002e"
                    android:text="2. WHERE TO APPLY THE TAPeE" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

           <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textColor="#da002e"
            android:text="3. HOW TIGHT TO TAPE" />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:padding="15dip"
                    android:textColor="#da002e"
                    android:text="2. WHERE TO APPLY THE TAPeE" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textColor="#da002e"
            android:text="4. HOW MUCH TAPE TO APPLY" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textColor="#da002e"
            android:text="5. WHEN TO REMOVE THE TAPE" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textColor="#da002e"
            android:text="6. HOW TO REMOVE THE TAPE" />
    </com.egoclean.android.widget.flinger.ViewFlinger>

</LinearLayout>
```

so, how to fix this please?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok got it,

is because i was using

> fill_parent

on the text view

using now

```
wrap_content
```

on the layout width and height, fixed it

;)